# How to call a jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, onclick

I have never used Jquery before and I was how I could call the following function from `onclick`of a button to work with a `textarea`

**function**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#demo1').highlightTextarea({
        words: {
          color: 'red',
          words: ['N/A','n/a']
        },
        debug: true
    });
```

An example of the code i'm looking at is the following:

**html Code**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

  <link href="css/jquery.highlighttextarea.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <script src="js/jquery.highlighttextarea.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<textarea rows="4" cols="50">
This is a example n/a of all the following N/A
Thanks 
</textarea>

<button type="button" onclick= >Call function </button>

<script type='text/javascript'> 
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#demo1').highlightTextarea({
        words: {
          color: 'red',
          words: ['N/A','n/a']
        },
        debug: true
    });

});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Thanks for the help, in advance

Comment: Why did you bother changing anything ??
I had asked the question I wanted and Mohamed-Yousef provided me with the solution I was looking for !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<script type='text/javascript'> 
$(document).ready(function() {
    highlight_Textarea(); // to run the function after document ready
});
function highlight_Textarea(){
    $('#demo1').highlightTextarea({
        words: {
          color: 'red',
          words: ['N/A','n/a']
        },
        debug: true
    });
}

</script>
```

and in html

```
<button type="button" onclick="highlight_Textarea()"></button>
```

or you can use it without onclick attribute

```
<script type='text/javascript'> 
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('button[type="button"]').on('click',function(){
             $('#demo1').highlightTextarea({
                 words: {
                 color: 'red',
                 words: ['N/A','n/a']
             },
              debug: true
             });
        });
    });
</script>
```

and in html

```
<button type="button"></button>
```

> Note: before everything be sure to set the Id demo1 to your textarea

```
<textara id="demo1"  ......
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the better way is to identify your button by an `id` and asign the click event to it using `on()` method.

**HTML :**

```
<button type="button" id="my-button">Call funciton</button>
```

**JS :**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('body').on( 'click' , '#my-button', function(){
        $('#demo1').highlightTextarea({
          words: {
            color: 'red',
            words: ['N/A','n/a']
          },
          debug: true
        });
    });
});
```

Hope this helps.